# Can tools or addins created in ArcMap be published and used in ArcGis Online?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online, python-addin, python-script-tool

I'm attempting to build an interactive map that would be hosted in AGOL. It would be a network query, whereupon selecting a point feature from an "inlet" layer, the map would display the corresponding (down-tree) "outlet" point feature. The point features on the network are connected by poly-lines with "upstream" and "downstream" fields that correspond to ID fields in the "inlet" and "outlet" tables.

I've created a .gdb in ArcMap, and have published the layers to AGOL succesfully, but am now unsure how to approach the scripting necessary for functionality. Can I create a tool/addin in ArcMap using Python, and then publish to AGOL? Or can I create a tool within AGOL itself? I'm having trouble finding a clear answer in any of ESRI's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot publish your own Geoprocessing Service to AGOL. (GP Service being the closest thing to what you describe based on using Python)

You can conduct queries and using the Web App Builder you can use widgets to help guide a user performing a query.

However based on what you're after, it sounds like some sort of geometric network trace. (or maybe a watershed trace?) For this you'll need to publish the tool to do this work to your own ArcGIS Server. (Note, there is a watershed tool available on ArcGIS.com, but you cannot use your own source DEMs)

Comment: You were close, it's a municipal storm-water utility network. I suppose it makes sense that I'd need to run the tool on my own server, as I would be essentially "stealing" processing power from ESRI servers otherwise. I may just need to stay in-box and write a tool within ArcMap. Thanks!

Comment: Its not that you'd be stealing processing power - its more a question of security. Allowing the publishing of GP Services to someone else servers (like arcgis.com) means there needs to be a mechanism in place to ensure you arent executing malicious code there.